# Drupal 7 upload document to Alfresco 4

Tags: php, file, drupal, alfresco, cmis

I've been working with the Drupal [CMIS API module](https://drupal.org/project/cmis) recently and think it works great. However, i've now been tasked to upload only a file attachment to a specific directory into Alfresco when creating a new Drupal node/page.

I've created a new content type in Drupal that holds some basic fields, including the file attachment field.

In Alfresco, i have a folder as /Documents/Private/ and would like to know if anyone's familiar with a good method of uploading the Drupal file attachments directly into the Alfresco directory when the Drupal node is created.

I haven't been able to find any clear documentation online and thought to give stackoverflow a shot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Drupal hook + cmis library calls to save it to Alfresco?

Comment: Do you know which exact function from the lib is responsible for uploading attachments to alf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you search the Alfresco Forum?

This might be helpful:

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/uploading-file-alfresco-repository-using-alfrescorest-api

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/uploading-files-using-restful-10182013-1327